# Debug APK not signed correctly Android 2.1.1 [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES]

Tags: android

I have been coding on android since a year now. So I am kind of a newbie.

I upgraded my android studio from 1.3 to 2.1 and suddenly I am facing this error msg everytime i try to test run my app on a device.

'Installation failed since the device already has an application with the same package but a different signature.
In order to proceed, you have to uninstall the existing application.

WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!

Do you want to uninstall the existing application?'

I tried unistalling the app but still everytime it asks me for it. I tried to run on another device there is says APk is not signed correctly :(

Kindly any help will be highly appreciated as I have stuck on this problem for over a week.

Comment: that can happen if apk is compiled on one machine and deployed to device from there, go to another machine, build and deploy to said device again.

Answer (score 0):

You can sign your apps with your release key while keeping the debugging option - you just have to add your release key into Android Studio (or specify it on the command line if you are signing your apps there).

In Android Studio, right click on your app in the project browser and open module settings. Select your app's module and click on 'Signing' to make sure your release keystore is listed. Then under 'Build Types', make sure that the debug target and the release target share the same signing config, and that the debug target has debuggable set to true. They should now share the same key.

More information on app signing can be found in the Developer docs [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html).

I haven't heard of a downside to using the same key for debugging and for release, provided the private key is kept secure (read: not under version control).